# What type of screw drivers should I use to service my laptop?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, screws

I'm getting ready to service my laptop and for that I need to completely disassemble it to the mobo level and clean it for liquid damage/corrosion. The laptop is a HP dv7-7227cl. All of the disassemble guides I've seen use some sort of magnetic screw driver so that the screws don't get lost by falling into the components. I've never disassembled something this complex before so I want to make sure I have the right tools. Also, is a static wrist band necessary? I'm low on budget so please suggest something affordable. I don't want to buy a whole set if I'm going to use only one out of the whole set and plus I only have to use it this one time. The manual says I need a phillips p1, and p0. I guess that is the size but after doing a quick search, I couldn't figure out if they were magnetic or not. So please suggest what screwdriver or where I should look to find them.

Comment: Magnetic screwdrivers just make your life easier, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to buy a whole set if I'm going to use only one out of the whole set and plus I only have to use it this one time.

Actually you mentioned that you need two sizes out of a set.
Assuming that you will use a general-purpose tool such as a screwdriver only one time in your life is ridiculously short-sighted.  If you're game enough to take apart a computer today, you actually think you will never use it again because you have a short life expectancy?

Avoid cheap tools (such as "jeweler's screwdrivers").  Quality tools can last almost a lifetime, whereas cheap, low-quality tools can damage your work or wear out. There seems to be different types of screwdrivers.  Home Depot, Lowe's and hardware stores seem to sell screwdrivers aimed at the carpentry/woodworking and automotive trades.  Electronic supply stores seem to carry a different type of screwdriver.  For example I could only find #1 and #2 Phillips screwdrivers with extra long 10" shaft at an electronic supply store.
[image]

Look for "hardened" tips that are a dull and a darker color (grey or black) than the rest of the (chromed) shaft.  Tips that are chromed like the entire shaft will flake and round over under heavy use.

[image]

My fav brands are Wiha and Xcelite (Cooper Tools).

Don't use the wrong size (esp undersized) screwdriver, or you risk damaging the screw head.

You probably do not need to wear an anti-static wrist-strap, but at the very least you should always discharge yourself of static electricity by touching something metal (that is grounded).

A pair of tweezers or needle-nose pliers or a hemostat can be very useful.

Regarding magnetic tip screwdrivers:
with high quality screwdrivers, you really don't need a magnetic tip.
The Phillips head screw will fit so snugly on the tip that the screw will stay in place by friction alone.  You probably have to actually use high quality screwdrivers to appreciate them over cheap tools.

Comment: My cheapo ones tend to last until I lose them. I occationally find one in some dark corner of the tool chest, and they seem fine. I've almost never stripped a small screw, except the time I tried to open up a security bit without a security bit screwdriver

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Apparently you haven't encountered the frozen/tight screws that I have that damage screw head and cheap screwdriver.

Comment: I NEVER force a screw if I can avoid it, which explains it. There's a bit of a technique to those, I do a 1 1/16th twist (just a little jiggle), stop, try it again.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek *"I NEVER force a screw if I can avoid it"* - Again, apparently you haven't encountered screws sealed with Locktite or frozen by corrosion.  These are screws that literally emit a "crack" sound when loosened the first time.  You use cheap tools; I get it.  But that doesn't make it good advice for others to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that your standard eyeglass screwdrivers work very well - I use something similar to these.

[image].

In a few cases I also have a set of security screwdriver heads such as torx, but this depends on the specific system.

I also recommend keeping a pill case handy , and labelling them with screw information, since many laptops have different lengths of screws.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a small screwdriver set you can buy from any store on...Radio shack, Home depot, your local hardware store.  You don't need a wristband as long as you don't go shuffling your feet along the carpet then touch any components.  ground yourself before you dive in and you'll be fine.  I've been up to my elbows in computer parts for years and never used a static wristband and have never fried a component. *knock on wood*