# This screw and the two like it are the bane of my existence

Tags: laptop-repair, hp-laptop

My laptop has taken to, reportedly, shooting up to 96C (206F) when the cpu (integrated graphics) is put to any use. Idling, mild browsing and it remaina 40-60C.

I've rolled back drivers, optimized settings. No progress.

I never feel any real warmth off it, the fan is mildly audible at all times and it has always had plenty of breathing room.

I have assaulted vents with a can of air.

I have done all this because I cannot get past these three screws. Two of my screwdrivers are barely too small (or perhaps they're not blunt enough), the pictured ones. Another is too fat. The head wont seat at all.

Because these are so tiny and the screwdrivers so sharp, tricks like rubber bands don't work.

I fully believe HP put these here just to keep non-professionals out most of the time.

Can anyone offer any diy advice?

Here is a link depicting that these screws are meant to be removed: https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/hp/hp-pavilion-15t-n200-touchsmart-cto-notebook-pc-energy-star/hp-pavilion-15-notebook-pc-hp-pavilion-touchsmart-15-notebook-pc-maintenance-and-service-guide/page-71.html

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Which size Philips screwdrivers have you tried using already?  Why not go buy a proper precision driver set?

Comment: You need to buy a specialised set of precision screwdrivers (bits) for computer/laptop disassembly. If you don't use the correct bit (exact size for the screw) you will strip the screw head and make it even harder to remove. Note: If you use some random old screwdriver the bit is probably too worn to work properly even it started off being the correct size.

Comment: What the other two said. Get the right tools and this won't be a problem.

Comment: Throw those two screwdrivers away. Even on your small jpg you can see how badly worn they are; they're good for nothing any more [& by the look of the handles wouldn't have been much better when new.] Cheap screwdrivers are worse than none at all - at least with none at all you can't ruin the screw-heads.

Comment: "mild browsing " - Most browsers can be hardware accelerated.  So when you say "mild browsing" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Your link specifies the screws (two different sizes).  Make sure the screwdrivers are the exact spec (and not worn).

Comment: Choose screwdrivers with hardened tips.  http://superuser.com/questions/602671/what-type-of-screw-drivers-should-i-use-to-service-my-laptop/602945#602945

Comment: @Ramhound youtube videos are usually okay.. Flash games kick it into overdrive. // The stores near me didnt have screwdrivers that fit, til I checked ACE. Screws, on to trying to remove the "face"  (around kb, has mousepad. Etc)