# Recommended screws and screwdrivers on a laptop (more exactly Lenovo ThinkPad E490s)

Tags: maintenance

When doing some maintenance work on a Lenovo Thinkpad (like installing RAM), the  manual instructions recommend using new screws. Is that so important?

If I decide to use new screws, what screws exactly should I use? Lenovo does not offer 'official screws'.

And what screwdriver would be the most apt for the work? I see that a common household Phillips screwdriver just fits, but wonder whether it would be better to use a JIS or Pozidrive? What tool would do the cleaner job?

My particular laptop does not have a service bay to replace HDD or RAM, you just have to pry open the whole back part. So I assume I'll could be opening it for new HDD soon, then new RAM sometime, new battery,  clean the fan.

I hope this question is not too trivial, but I just don't want to screw the new laptop.

Comment: You just need smaller size Phillips screwdrivers. Lenovo doesn't have "official screws" because they use standard threaded screws and heads. Only Apple uses proprietary heads that you can't find/pick up at any hardware store. Something like this [iFixit kit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/Essential-Electronics-Toolkit/IF145-348?o=2) would cover your current needs.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/602671/what-type-of-screw-drivers-should-i-use-to-service-my-laptop

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to buy a new screw kit if you don't lose any screws and if you have a screwdriver that is in good shape. I have a Phillips Wiha PH0 x 50 mm that fits most of my Thinkpad screws (X250, T420, X61).

And yes, it's a shame that you can't change memory or the harddrive by just removing one or two screws. Thank you Lenovo!

Just be careful when you have to fiddle with these plastic clips. I tend to use those cell phone / ipod opening tools which are also made of plastic. Well, if don't use my fingernails...

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, a good quality screwdriver is a must. Other good brands include Wera and PB Swiss. Interchangeable bits are useful until you need to get into a deep hole.

Comment: On the brighter side, Lenovo's E-series is cheaper due to the lack of these convenient features.

Comment: @QuoraFeans But my newer X-series and T-series laptops also have no convenient features any more. These days are gone...